# Remove duplicate ID inside array

Tags: php, arrays

I have try to remove duplicated post with array_unique but seems not work in this way, i have try to add array_unique($array) after while but it's back me only one result, record_num is ID.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $array[] = $row;
}
array_unique($array)
foreach($array as $row) {
   .....
}
```

Array example

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [record_num] => 18152
            [title] => Title of post 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [record_num] => 18150
            [title] => Title of post 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [record_num] => 18134
            [title] => Title of post 3
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [record_num] => 18134
            [title] => Title of post 3
        )
}
```

Comment: `array_unique()` returns a new array. What happens if you try `$array = array_unique($array);`?

Comment: What do you want to happen to the `title` data? As you will have a single `record_num` but multiple, different, `title` element values

Comment: Yes, it should work only for simple arrays. Please see another functions or make an additional loops.

Comment: check this out from the php array_unique documentation itself http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#116302

Comment: @rickdenhaan same.

Comment: You should read the php `array_unique` function documentation. Try `$new_array = array_unique($array)`, then loop `foreach($new_array as $row)...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function like this

```
function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) { 
$temp_array = array(); 
$i = 0; 
$key_array = array(); 

foreach($array as $val) { 
    if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) { 
        $key_array[$i] = $val[$key]; 
        $temp_array[$i] = $val; 
    } 
    $i++; 
} 
return $temp_array; 
}
```

and call it like

```
unique_multidim_array($details,'record_num');
```

Comment: Hmm looks promising, i will try it now

Comment: Working, it's a just what i need

Answer (score 8):

You can use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to remove duplicates from a multidimensional array.
[Array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) returns one column of an array, but if you set the second parameter to `null` and the third to `record_num` it will remove the duplicates.

```
$arr = array_values(array_column($arr, null, 'record_num'));
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["record_num"]=>
    int(18152)
    ["title"]=>
    string(14) "Title of post "
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["record_num"]=>
    int(18150)
    ["title"]=>
    string(15) "Title of post 2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["record_num"]=>
    int(18134)
    ["title"]=>
    string(15) "Title of post 3"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/jEvWG

Comment: Yeah but  array_column is a function in PHP 5.5+ i have older

Comment: @Darko1996 if you have problem with `array_column()` because of  php version then you can use the User Contributed code at php.net for lower version of php. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php#117229

Comment: @Darko1996 why are you using that old version of PHP?  There are plenty of benefits if you upgrade

Comment: It's a old project need to update 1000+ files for new version of php :(

Comment: You don't always have to update the PHP files just because you upgrade the version of the compiler. Some or most functions work but may display an notice.

Comment: yeah i know, definitely i will do when i have more free time

Answer (score 1):

**Actually you can do it by multiple way**, This way also work for you with `array_map()` and `array_unique()`

```
$result = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));
print_r($result);
```

**RESULT:**

```
Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( 
   [record_num] => 18152
   [title] => Title of post 
 )
 [1] => Array ( 
   [record_num] => 18150
   [title] => Title of post 2 
 ) 
 [2] => Array (
   [record_num] => 18134
   [title] => Title of post 3 
 )
)
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/PbRAp